# Techniques for debugging matplotlib animation?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

In creating some matplotlib animations (FFMpeg or ImageMagick to `mp4` files, in my case), I have been running into errors like this

```
RuntimeError: Error creating movie, return code: 1
```

They are not very useful for figuring out what is going wrong.  What are some ways to debug this?   Can I get a `list` of argument arrays or something?  Run a *PyCharm* debugger with a useful breakpoint?

I am open to all helpful suggestions.

Comment: First debugging step is always to create a [mcve]. It might also help to create an example with the minimal difference to the non-working example which actually works. In this case, does the animation actually play on screen? Can it be saved to an animated gif? Is ffmpeg in your path and callable? I also wonder if you really get a one-line error message? Usually python is more verbose and provides full traceback. You may in addition set the matplotlib debugging level higher, such that it would tell you more about what it does.

Comment: Oh, and last but not least. If you are using PyCharm, always debug outside of PyCharm (as a script in terminal). PyCharm is often enough the actual problem itself.

Comment: The best thing I have found so far is to run a `DEBUG` level logging handler on `matplotlib.animation._log`.  This yields messages with stdout and stderr, from which I was able to tell exactly what command matplotlib was attempting to run, and debug the problem